# Making Handlers Generic

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, object-oriented-analysis

So I'm writing a C# System.Commandline app, and I've noticed that my methods all follow a similar structure - each Handler class has a single public method, RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode, taking a different set of options which I've encapsulated into a class to be passed as the parameter. Like below:

```
public class FirstHandler
{
    public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(FirstOptions options) { }
}

public class SecondHandler
{
    public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(SecondOptions options) { }
}
```

And so on. I've tried making an OptionsBase abstract class, and having my other Options classes inherit from it, then created a handler interface like the below:

```
internal interface IHandler
    {
        int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode<T>(T options) where T : OptionsBase;
    }
```

With the handlers looking like:

```
public class FirstHandler : IHandler
{
    public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode<FirstOptions>(FirstOptions options) { }
}
```

Edit: I also have the Options classes inheriting from OptionsBase:

```
public class FirstOptions : OptionsBase
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And the OptionsBase class:

```
public abstract class OptionsBase { }
```

But this returns the error "The constraints for type parameter 'FirstOptions' must match the constraints for type parameter T. (Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead).

Where am I going wrong? Is this even the right approach?

Comment: `FirstOptions` must inherit `OptionsBase`.

Comment: Apologies, it does, will add to my original question

Comment: Seems you must add the constraint on the method as well.
`public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode<FirstOptions>(FirstOptions options) where FirstOptions : OptionsBase {
    return 0;
}`

Comment: it depends on what your `OptionsBase` is, put it in the description

Comment: @TornikeCholadze have added it now

Comment: @Hazrelle I've tried that now, and I can't access any of the properties on FirstOptions from within the method for some reason.

If it helps, and apologies for my crude explanation, the FirstOptions type in the parameters is light green in VS, the same as an interface, rather than the usual dark green of a class...

Answer (score 0):

you are setting abstraction and constraints on function level, which means whichever class will implement that interface will implement an abstract method with its constraints.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new GenericHandler<FirstOptions>().RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(new FirstOptions
        {
            FirstProperty = "FirstOptionProp",
            SomeBaseOptionOne = 1,
            SomeBaseOptionTwo = 2,
        });
        new FirstHandler().RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(new FirstOptions
        {
            FirstProperty = "FirstOptionProp",
            SomeBaseOptionOne = 1,
            SomeBaseOptionTwo = 2,
        }); ;
    }
}

public abstract class OptionsBase
{
    public int SomeBaseOptionOne { get; set; }
    public int SomeBaseOptionTwo { get; set; }
}

public class FirstOptions : OptionsBase
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
}

internal interface IHandler<T>
    where T : OptionsBase
{
    int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(T options);
}

public class FirstHandler : IHandler<FirstOptions>
{
    public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(FirstOptions options)
    {
        return options.SomeBaseOptionTwo;
    }
}

public class GenericHandler<T> : IHandler<T>
{
    public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(T options)
    {
        //TODO: do some generic imlementation

        return 0;
    }
}
```

you can register it in services as:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler<FirstOptions>), typeof(FirstHandler))
services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler<>), typeof(GenericHandler<>))
```

Comment: Couldn't get the first variation here to work, but realised I need to create a new variable, for example opts = options as FirstOptions, now it works!

Comment: @GaryMacGregor-Manzi I edited check it now

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Wouldn't I then need to register in DI each different handler? I'd end up with lots of:
services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler<>), typeof(FirstHandler<>))
services.AddScoped(typeof(IHandler<>), typeof(SecondHandler<>))

etc?

Comment: you need to register each handler one by one but for each handler, you can have different options, generic type here is the Options object, not the handler itself

Comment: if you want to have Generic handler for different options it's slightly different imlementation

Comment: Ah I see - yeah, generic handler with different options is what I was hoping for, I think

Comment: @GaryMacGregor-Manzi check update

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I think I've maybe got myself mixed up - the RunHanlder method isn't doing generic things, so I think you were right to have IHandler<T>

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are trying to do, you can do it like the following.

The Interface should have the Generic Type set on it, ie. `IHandler<T> where T : OptionsBase`, Then have separate implementations of the `FirstHandler` and `SecondHandler`.

```
public class OptionsBase
{

}

public class FirstOptions : OptionsBase
{

}

public class SecondOptions : OptionsBase
{

}

internal interface IHandler<T> where T : OptionsBase
{
    int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(T options);
}

public class FirstHandler : IHandler<FirstOptions>
{
    public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(FirstOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}    

public class SecondHandler : IHandler<SecondOptions>
{
    public int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(SecondOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This gives you the ability to test each handler individually, introduce a base abstract class, and also use DependencyInjection for the options: Like the following example:

```
public abstract class AbstracHandler<T> : IHandler<T> where T : OptionsBase
{
    protected readonly T _options;

    public AbstracHandler(T options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }
    public abstract int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(T options);
}

public class FirstHandler : AbstracHandler<FirstOptions>
{
    public FirstHandler(FirstOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public override int RunHandlerAndReturnExitCode(FirstOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try! You've even answered part of my next question in advance, though I'm left with a follow-up: how would I register the handlers in dependency injection? I'm just using the default .NET dependency injection system

Comment: not quite sure how you will register them, that totally depends on the way your app works. Are the options read from a config file? Or are created run-time? This will vary the way your object is created.
You could also opt for a Factory Class - pass in the Options to a method to get the correct Handler.

Comment: The options are parsed from args on the command line, so they're created long after all dependencies have been injected (so my understanding from what I've tried so far is that the constructor taking OptionsBase won't work in this situation?)

Comment: So I can do:
services.AddScoped<IHandler<FirstOptions>, FirstHandler>();

But then I'd need to register each type manually, surely that isn't right?